# the $n$th derivative of the series $\sum a_n x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) =\sum a_n x^n $  $\ $
Now I have proved that 
$$f^{(n)}(x) = \sum n! a_n$$.
But the question is to prove 
$$f^{(n)}(0) = n! a_n$$

Maybe I don't understand the series pretty well. I think I just proved that the derivative is not related to $x$. Are there any problems?

Comment: You lost your $x$'s in the first step, and you probably want to keep your summation variable distinct from the number of derivatives you're taking.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of $f^{(n)}(x)$ is incorrect.

$$\begin{align}f^{(n)}(x)&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty n(n-1)\ldots(k-n+1)a_kx^{k-n}\\
&=n!a_n+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty n(n-1)\ldots(k-n+1)a_kx^{k-n}.
\end{align}$$

Now plug $0$ in for $x$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I finally understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your quite welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a derivative is indeed a function of $x$.  For instance, ${\partial x^2 \over \partial x} = 2 x$.  All your question is asking is that after you take a derivative (which will, in general, be a function of $x$), then replace the value $x = 0$.